# How to upload image to folder and name to database using python

Tags: python, database, image, upload, using

here is my code to upload images to folder and name to the database and it isn't working.
i am getting an error **'bytes' object has no attribute 'image' Exception occured**

```
 #html code  -->#

<html>
    <head>
        <TITLE> Product Image</TITLE>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="productimg.py" method=post>
            <table align=center  cellspacing=20 cellpadding=10 >
                <th align="center" colspan=3 > <u>Upload Image of the Goods</u></th>
                <tr ><th  colspan="4"> Enter your details below and wait minimum for half an hour.</th></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Product Image  :  </td><td> <input type=file name="image" accept = "image/*"    accept=".png/*" value="image"> </td>

                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td> </td> <td> <input type=Submit > <input type=Reset> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

i am getting an error **'bytes' object has no attribute 'image' Exception occured** in pyhton code.

#python code  -->#

```
#!C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
print('Content-type:text/html\n\r')
import cgi
import sys
from myconnect import *
message=0
try:
    con,cur=myconnect()
    form= cgi.FieldStorage()
    # Get  here.
    fileitem=form.getvalue('image');
    #fileitem = form['image']
    # Test if the file was uploaded
    if fileitem.image:
        # strip leading path from file name to avoid
        # directory traversal attacks
        fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.image)
        open('/uploads/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
        message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
        query=f"select product_delivery_id from tbl_product_deliver order by product_delivery_id desc"  
        cur.execute(query) 
        pid=cur.fetchone()

        update=f"UPDATE `tbl_product_deliver` SET `product_image`='{fn}' WHERE `product_delivery_id`='{pid}'"
        cur.execute(update)
        con.commit()
    else:
       message = 'No file was uploaded'
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Exception occured")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use a python script like php. Typically you have to configure an eventhandler waiting for a post-request. For doing this in python you need a framework like **flask** or **bottle** for receiving post request and instead of **productimg.py** you use the route you've set with this framework as **action** in html.
2. Your **FieldStorage object** is called without arguments, so you create an empty Fieldstorge object with no data.

A FieldStorage object receiving a post request looks like this:

```
fs= FieldStorage(fp=request.body, headers=request.headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST', 'CONTENT_TYPE':request.headers['Content-Type'], })
```

However ensure you solved issue 1 before doing issue 2.

With bottle use this python code:

```
from bottle import post, request, run
@post('/upload')
def getImage():
    #printing the raw data
    print(request.body)
    #insert your code here
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

and change in html:
`action="http://localhost:8080/upload`

Good luck

Comment: can we simply use file handling to insert images to folder and names to databases, or is there any other way  without using flask and bottle because I am beginner in python

Comment: If you want to use the html i don't know a simplier way than using one of these. You just have pip installed and call pip install bottle to do like i added to my answer.

Comment: If you don't need to use any UI you can open the file with `file = open("example.png", "r")`

Comment: Or using any other UI like Tk (I'm not experienced with python UI's)